# Cannot import a local CocoaPod after install

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to import a development pod. I have created my `CocoaPod` using XCode by selecting `New > Cocoa Touch Framework`.

I have then generated `.podspec` and verified it is correct via `pod lint`.

That has been added to my project `Podfile` and on running `Pod Install` I can see the correct version number added as a dependency.

The issue is when I try and then import this in a file, the module does not appear in intellisense nor does it compile if I just try and build it.

My Cocoa project looks like this

[image]

and my `.podspec` looks like this

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.platform = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
s.name = "HomeComponents"
s.summary = "Common Home Components"
s.requires_arc = true
s.version = "1.0.3"
s.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
s.author = { "xxx xxx" => "xxx@xxx.xxx" }
s.homepage = "https://xxx/xxx/xxx"
s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

s.framework = "UIKit"

s.source_files = "Sources/**/*.{swift}"
s.resources = "Sources/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets}"
s.swift_version = "4.0"
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this is not working. The pod installs, but is just not available in my app. I have it declared with the correct target so I am sure it should be being installed.

Comment: I am taking a guess here, since I have not created a dev pod before, but i hope you are using a workspace file and not xcode proj file.

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct file, but thank you :)